# How to get the first object name in JSON data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

My server guy is sending me the JSON data with different objects on different requests in a message object. Like, in some requests:

```
{
            "message": {
                "series": {...}
            },
            "boolean": true
}
```

and in some requests:

```
{
            "message": {
                "movie": {...}
            },
            "boolean": true
}
```

And both objects has different data. so, I want to get the name of first object that it's "movie" or "series" in message object, so that i can make an if else condition on it to get inside data.

```
    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getVideo=1"];
    // Create Data from request
    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    // set Request Type
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    // Set content-type
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    // Set Request Body
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    // Now send a request and get Response
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
    // Log Response
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

//    for(NSDictionary *dict in firstObject){
//        NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"name"]);
//    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use AFNetworking framework for communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict = [dict objectForKey:@"message"];
if([dict objectForKey:@"movie"]){
//Your dictionary has key movie, parse accordingly
}
else if ([dict objectForKey:@"series"]){
 //Your dictionary has key series, parse accordingly
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "first object" in `NSDictionary`. The contents are not ordered.

You can check for the presence of object/key pairs easily by trying to access them:

```
id value = dict[@"someKey"];
```

will give you the stored object or `nil` if there's no object for `@"someKey"`.

You can also iterate over the complete dictionary using

```
- enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current scenarios, you can get the first key of message following the below:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"message": @{
                               @"movies": @"heros"
                               }
                       };

NSLog(@"%@", [[dict[@"message"] allKeys] firstObject]);
```

But, I recommend fetching different data with different api endpoint.

Comment: allKeys retuns keys in an undefined order, so using firstObject is dangerous unless you know you only have one key